# Making .war smaller

Tags: grails, groovy, shared-libraries

There are several tutorials and even some posts here about shrinking .war files. However, the most common technique (to include grails.war.resources = {} in Config.groovy) does not seem to work for me. No matter what, grails dumps everything into the war file making a 25meg .war. Has this functionality changed? Grails 1.3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im on 1.2.0

```
grails war --nojars
```

creates a war with no jars.

You have to make sure your jars are properly installed on wherever you are deploying, so

$tomcat/shared/lib

for tomcat.

Comment: I cannot believe it was that simple. The grails documentation really leaves something to be desired, its a mix of outdated examples, broken links, misleading statements and some things that are simply wrong. Thanks for your fast reply!

Comment: @quad64bit, yeah you have to do some digging sometimes with grails.  I find the IRC helpful; also mailing lists are active.

Comment: I found google to be generally the best source of information. You just have to formulate the question in such a way the results are what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

For tomcat6 and later remember to update your catalina.properties file:

shared.loader=${catalina.home}/**yourDirectoryName**/*.jar

You will need to ensure that ${catalina.home}/**yourDirectoryName** exists and that it contains all the grails WEB-INF/lib jars in it.